# How to obtain a reference to a CGFloat using init() in Swift?

Tags: swift, cgfloat

I am new to programming with Swift (with a Java background) and I am trying to initialise a CGFloat using the init() method. I also need a reference to  CGFloat after it is initialised. I keep trying this like I'd do in Java:

```
CGFloat _cgFloat = CGFloat.init(10);
```

Quite evidently as the IDE indicates, this is an error. I don't seem to understand how to work around this. What am I doing wrong ? Isn't there a way to make this work like in Java:

```
Object a = new Object();
```

A solution to this would be most appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop the init, simply use `CGFloat(10)` - and no need for the `;` in the end

Comment: `CGFloat _cgFloat =`  causes the syntax error, not the `CGFloat.init(10);`. – Note also that `CGFloat` is a *value type* and not an "object".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init` methods are written like this in Swift:

```
let newFloat = CGFloat(10)
```

Comment: and just one other thing, so wherever I see an init(..) that's actually a constructor and I need to use the method without init () but retain the rest of the signature in parenthesis preceded by the class's name? Hope I got that right ...

Comment: You can write also .init in Swift, during code development in Xcode, if you type init Xcode give to you a code auto-completion, it's more useful..

Comment: I would not recommend using the `init` keyword. It just makes for more clutter in your code. If you want Xcode autocompletion, start typing the class followed by an opening parenthesis  (in this case `CGFloat(`) and you will see the possible completions.